# is mp4parser java library has android version

Tags: android, mp4parser

I'm trying to use mp4parser library in android and I encountered some difficulties.
I'm guessing it is becuase mp4parser is a java based project and not adapted yet to android.

PS - mp4parser is worldly spread and even being used by Instagram

I'm basing my conclusions on the following pice of code:

```
 public PropertyBoxParserImpl(String... customProperties) {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/isoparser-default.properties");
    mapping = new Properties();
    try {
        mapping.load(is);
        Enumeration<URL> enumeration = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("isoparser-custom.properties");

        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL url = enumeration.nextElement();
            mapping.load(url.openStream());
        }
        for (String customProperty : customProperties) {
            mapping.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(customProperty));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

isoparser-default.properties is a reflaction mapping:

```
hint=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.TrackReferenceTypeBox(type)
cdsc=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.TrackReferenceTypeBox(type)
meta-ilst=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleItemListBox()
-----name=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleNameBox()
-----mean=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleMeanBox()
-----data=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleDataBox()
rmra=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleReferenceMovieBox()
rmda=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleReferenceMovieDescriptorBox()
rmdr=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleDataRateBox()
rdrf=com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleDataReferenceBox()
```

in android you cant initiate a url with a link to a local class and mehod and load it like 
the above PropertyBoxParserImpl() does.

So I'm guessing that I'll just need to change the following function, does anyone enocountered those issues while using the mp4parser?

Comment: Did you managed to modify it? Mp4 parser does work on android using isoviewer-1.0-RC-35.jar but I can't use Proguard if using this library since it detects problems with references to awt classes.

Comment: PSIXO I was managed to work with it but never try to proguard it. Does the references to awt classes are mandatory? Maybe you should try change them to Android libraries it it possible

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I did have a similar idea (To remove awt classes) but then got problems because many of library parts are based on reflection API. Removing this seemed too complicated to me because of huge number of mappings done this way. On the other hand this solved the problem and Proguard runs now
-keep public class * implements com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Box

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. Download both isoparser-1.0-RC-27.jar and aspectj-rt.jar, and include them in your libs folder.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.3/

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/mp4parser/isoparser/